# How can I find the uwp template in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

My OS is Windows 10(Insider Preview).I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.2(26430.15)，the newest version.And I want to use Universal Windows Platform (UWP) templates,but I can't find it.

Now I can't write the UWP program.

What's wrong with my Visual Studio?Did I miss something?Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can download [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) and try out various UWP templates.

If you don't have uwp components installed, make sure you tick the first option(Universal Windows Platform Development) from the list during VS2017 installation.

[image]

Check out this [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/selecting-workloads-visual-studio-2017/).

Comment: Sorry for reply you so late.I tried the Windows Template Studio,it works.Something need to correct that my VS2017 is community version but not the Enterprise version.And in VS2017 installation I can't see the option(Universal Windows Platform Development) you showed,if beaucase of I am using the community version?